# Remove the character alone from the string

Tags: vb.net

My code retrieves the data from various resources .

And output will be like below

**UNY4/4/2010**

**hds04/5/2010**

**saths04/22/2013**

But I want the output like this

**4/4/2010**

**4/5/2010**

**04/22/2013**

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: I'd try capturing the date part with a regular expression I think - try `@"\d{1,2}?\/\d{1,2}?\/\d{4}"` as a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression that finds all uppercase and lowercase characters and replaces them with a blank, like this:

```
Dim rgx As New Regex("[a-zA-Z]")
str = rgx.Replace(str, String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is to look for the first numeric digit, then discard all text before that.

```
Function GetDate(data As String) As Date
    Dim indexFirstNum As Integer = data.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray())
    Dim datePortion As String = data.Substring(indexFirstNum)
    Return Date.Parse(datePortion)
End Function
```

Comment: One More Perfect solution.. :)